# rake db:seed unable to read CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv, rake

I was going to populate my PostgreSQL database from CSV files, but when I do `rake db:seed` I got this error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  could not open file "/home/spondbob/projects/rhsystem/db/data/doctors.csv" for reading: Permission denied
: COPY doctors(
    name,
    address,
    phone,
    field_id,
    is_active,
    email,
    encrypted_password,
    reset_password_token,
    reset_password_sent_at,
    remember_created_at,
    sign_in_count,
    current_sign_in_at,
    last_sign_in_at,
    current_sign_in_ip,
    last_sign_in_ip) 
FROM '/home/spondbob/projects/rhsystem/db/data/doctors.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
/home/spondbob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rhsystem/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'

...
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't have read permission, I've made sure the permission is there and database connection is well established. Here is the file permission:

```
$ ls -l db/data                     
total 56
-rwxr-xr-x 1 spondbob users   775 Dec 17 12:46 doctors.csv
...
```

And my `seeds.rb` for first table:

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
connection.execute("COPY doctors(
    name,
    address,
    phone,
    field_id,
    is_active,
    email,
    encrypted_password,
    reset_password_token,
    reset_password_sent_at,
    remember_created_at,
    sign_in_count,
    current_sign_in_at,
    last_sign_in_at,
    current_sign_in_ip,
    last_sign_in_ip) 
FROM '#{Rails.root.join('db','data')}/doctors.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER")
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is `/home/spondbob/rhsystem` also world readable/executable?  If any part of that isn't then it will fail.

Comment: The root folder actually is `/home/spondbob/projects/rhsystem`, I've corrected it. And yes it has r/x as well.

Comment: I just found out that the user `postgres` unable to access `/home/spondbob` even I've put it into group `users`

Answer (score 1):

Create a rake task for that:

```
desc "Imports a CSV file into an ActiveRecord table"
task :csv_import, :filename, :model, :needs => :environment do |task,args|
  lines = File.new(args[:filename]).readlines
  header = lines.shift.strip
  keys = header.split(',')
  lines.each do |line|
    params = {}
    values = line.strip.split(',')
    keys.each_with_index do |key,i|
      params[key] = values[i]
    end
    Module.const_get(args[:model]).create(params)
  end
end
```

and then use it like this:

> rake csv_import file.csv model

Comment: Thx @Paulo for your answer, but I just found out the problem. It was the persmission of `/home/spondbob` was 700. Thats why the group `users` doesn't have permission r/x on it.

Comment: @spondbob yes, but that way you are always relaying on changing permissions. Remember if you change the server you'll need to setup permissions instead of uploading the file somewhere.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, thx mate. I'll note down this one.